# SQL Syntax when changing fixed date to sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query I'm updating and one of the items is switching to a dynamic date based on sysdate, can't seem to get the syntax right for the change. You can see below, first line works, I've tried to replace it with the last line several different ways with no luck. I searched but can't quite find the right example for this.

```
TO_DATE('12-17-2022 18:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('12-18-2022 17:59:59','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')


TO_DATE(('Sysdate - 2) 18:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE(('Sysdate -1) 17:59:59','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use `TO_DATE` as `SYSDATE` is already a `DATE`.

You can either add `INTERVAL`s to `SYSDATE` `TRUNC`ated back to midnight:

```sql
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '2' DAY + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '17:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
```

or combining the intervals:

```sql
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1 6:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - '6:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND
```

or, add fractions of days:

```sql
BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2 + 18/24 
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 + 18/24 - 1/24/60/60
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was something fundamentally wrong but couldn't figure out what it is. Works perfectly now, many thanks and hope you have happy holidays!